# Acoustic phonons velocity of GaN

Tags: semiconductor-physics, spectroscopy, phonons, dispersion

Phonons dispersion is presented at figure below: T. Ruf. “Phonon Dispersion Curves in Wurtzite-Structure GaN Determined by Inelastic X-Ray Scattering”. In: Physical Review Letters 86.5 (2001), pp. 906–909. 
I would like to know the acoutics phonon velocity from $\Gamma$ to $A$ point. As far i know that this velocity could be determined from the slope by relations:

$$ v_g = \frac{d \omega}{dk}$$

So lets starts from defining what is value of **1 r.l.u** (reciprocal lattice units), for lattice parameter $a =3.145 \cdot 10^{-10} \approx \pi \cdot 10^{-10} \ m $.

\begin{equation}
0.5 \ {r.l.u} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\pi}{a}= \frac{1}{2} \cdot  \frac{\pi}{\pi \cdot 10^{-10}} = 0.5 \cdot 10^{10} \ {m}^{-1}
\end{equation}
Now from the figure the acoustic phonons frequency is $230 \ cm^{-1} $, and by multiplying this by light velocity $c = 3 \cdot 10^{10} \ cm/s $ a $d \omega =  690 \cdot 10^{10} \ s^{-1}$

Finally:

\begin{equation}
v_{phonons} = \frac{690 \cdot 10^{10}}{0.5 \cdot 10^{10}} = 1380   \ \left[ \frac{{m}}{{s}} \right]
\end{equation}

unfortunally an literature tells that the acoustic phonon velocity in GaN is equal  $8.04 \cdot 10^3 \left[ \frac{{m}}{{s}} \right]$, so mine results is far away from this value. Where is an mistake?

- [image: GaN Phonons]

Comment: Phonons don’t ‘go’ from $\Gamma$ to A - that is in reciprocal space. Phonons keep their $k$ value and move through real space.

Comment: In scattering theory an value of longitudinal acoustic phonon velocity is needed. So I supposed that this velocity could by estimated from the slope of the acoutic branch in GaN dispersion relation from $\Gamma$ to $A$ point as many researches connects this group velocity with acoustic phonons velocity. From you suggestion I cannot find appropriate value. Second point of view connecting this acoustic velocity with elastic constants and GaN density.